# Python list manipulation: issue in copying array

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice

I have the following code which produces an unexpected output.

```
arr1 = [i for i in range(10)]
temp = [None]*20
top=10
temp[0:top+1] = arr1
```

After execution, why does the length of 'temp' array reduce from 20 to 19?

Comment: because you replace 11 element with 10 by the last line

Comment: because `arr` has 10 elements and you are replacing a segment of `temp` which has 11 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your `temp[0:top+1] = arr1` line is wrong, it should be `temp[0:top] = arr1`.

`arr1` is of length `10` but your are trying to add `11` items from `arr1` and as one of the value doesn't exists, it is giving this output.